# I can not open multiple modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I just created a modal but I have the view multiple times. I can not because if I click Open Modal 1 it works but not on Open Modal 2

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example 1</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal 1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<h2>Modal Example 2</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal 2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: We need some source code to take a look...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/foufouner/d0jb49a7/

Comment: @user3831928 Do *not* link to external sites for the source code. [Edit] your question + paste all code that is necessary. Please also read how to post a  [MVCE]

Comment: Do not link to external sites for the source code. [Edit] your question + paste all code that is necessary. Please also read how to post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code on jsfiddle, one cannot have two elements with the same ID on html (and expect them to work properly).

Here's your original code (you have two elements with the `myBtn` id):

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

You could, instead, make all the buttons have the same class (`modalbtn`, for instance), and use a code to go trough each button and set the callback, like so:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("modalbtn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  var btn = btns[i];
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  };
}
```

Just for clarification: The `document.getElementById()` function will return, at most, ONE value.

### Edit 2

If you want to have different actions for different buttons, You need to make a callback for each button (or work with a data stored inside the button, but I'm not going into this level of details in this answer). Here's an example:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("modalbtn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  var btn = btns[i];
  btn.onclick = function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal-' + i);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  };
}
```

with that code, the first button will show the modal with id `myModal-0`, and the second button the modal with id `myModal-1` and so on...

### Edit

Here is the original answer (both buttons open the same modal):

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("modalbtn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  var btn = btns[i];
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  };
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example 1</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn1" class="modalbtn">Open Modal 1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<h2>Modal Example 2</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn2" class="modalbtn">Open Modal 2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I've edited the answer with your code and the code I suggest you replace it with. Don't forget to add the class to the buttons.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason the `forEach()` call does not work on the value returned by `getElementsByClassName()`. So, I've edited my answer without needing to use `forEach()`.

Comment: sorry but your code is not work because if clic in Modal Example 1 or Modal Example 2 the texte in class modal-content is the is the same

Comment: Yeah, the text is the same, because both buttons are performing the same function, which is open the same modal ID. If you want to open different modals, you'd need to create a callback for each button, each pointing to a different modal id. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: sorry but I do not have your answer

Answer (score 0):

Like Sergio mentioned you cannot have same id in DOM. So you can use `class` as an identifier

Hope this below snippet will be useful.

index will be useful if you want to refer to particular button in future

```
//openModal is class common to button
var _getButton = document.getElementsByClassName('openModal');
//Convert NodeList to array to use array methods
var btnArray=Array.prototype.slice.call(_getButton)
btnArray.forEach(function(item,index){ //forEach is Array method
(function(x){   //Creating closure to bind event with particular button
   item.addEventListener('click',function(){
    console.log(index)
       modal.style.display = "block";
   })
 }(index))

})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/d0jb49a7/4/)